# How to define type for all properties in an interface?

Tags: typescript

I'm defining an interface which provides strings in i18n application:

```
interface ILocaleStringsProvider {
  'foo': string
  'bar': string
  'baz': string
  'blablabla': string
  // hundreds of string properties here...
}
```

I don't like to repeat `: string` many times.

Is there a way to define the type of all properties at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `Record<K extends string, T>` type. If you have different types for different  fields you can use union types:

```
type ILocaleStringsProvider = 
    Record<'foo'|'bar'|'baz'|'blablabla',string> &
    Record<'foo2'|'bar2'|'baz2'|'blablabla2',number>;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Index, Union and in:

```
type ILocaleStringsProvider = {
    [i in 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz' | 'blablabla']: string
}
```